# How to execute a unit test project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

I have a visual studio project which only has Unit test test cases in C#. Like this:

```
namespace UnitTest.MyApplicaiton
{
    [TestClass]
   public class UnitTest_Class1
  {
 . ...
  }
}
```

how can I execute that unit test?
When I "Set as start up project" and then click 'Start", I get this error saying 
A project with an Output Type of Class library can not be start ed directly.

The project is already a unit test project, It  has this test tube icon overlay the project icon.

Answer (score 0):

1.On the Build menu, choose Build Solution.
2.Choose Run All to run the test.

For more details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx